# How to boost boot time in ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: 18.10

I newly purchased a new machine (specs- 8gb ram 1tb hdd i5 7th gen) and install Ubuntu 18.10 with single boot,but the booting time will take approximately 1 minuits 10 secs. Please suggest me any solution for this problem!
I really disappointed about that.

Comment: Not necessarily a problem. HDDs are slow and the CPU is no powerhouse either. And if you installed in Legacy mode even worse.

Comment: But it will take too much time!
is it normal or not  ?

Comment: We don't know what you installed additionally that may be running at the boot time, we don't know *how* the OS was installed. Your question is unanswerable as it is."Too much time" is your opinion.

Comment: Indeed, your question is way too vague and difficult for anyone to help you with.  You said the boot time takes 1:10.  How long did you expect?  1 minute?  50 seconds?  And on what are these expectations based on?  If you had two computers with identical specifications and one takes 1:10 and another 0:50, then I think someone can help you to get the former to match the latter.  But your question lacks any feasible goal.  If boot time was your aim, then you probably should have bought a better computer with an SSD.

Comment: But do make sure you are comparing fairly.  If the other computer has an SSD, then I seriously doubt there is a way to tune your computer to boot up as quickly.

Comment: Use the Search box to look at all the similar speed-up-my-boot questions that have been asked (and answered). If you don't provide detailed information about your boot, then you won't get useful advice tailored to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider different options:

> 1. Installing Ubuntu 16.04 will do faster both booting and working.
> 2. Install SSD drive and run the OS from it - will extremely increase speed of both booting and working.
> 3. Remove Startup Apps if any.
> 4. Change the desktop manager to the smaller and faster - LXDE, Xfce and etc

Comment: I am new in ubuntu, please let me know how to do that?

Comment: which option does seem attractive to you?